# NSCalendar week number of date

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

I am trying to get the week number from a date. Can someone please tell me why this is only returning 0 no matter what date I put in there:

```
let currentWeekNumber = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear, fromDate: myDate).weekOfYear
```

The format of myDate is like this 2015-01-23 11:52:35 +0000

A solution in Swift would be nice :)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. With `let myDate = NSDate()`, your code returns the (correct) value  `4`.

Comment: A (small) self-contained example with input data, actual and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Martin. I messed up the input date somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your posted line has no error. Just check the below solution to confirm if result is same.

**Note:** Just trying to eliminate any possiblity of irrelevant issue due to date.
For Swift you can use.

```
let calender = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let dateComponent = calender.components(NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYearCalendarUnit  | NSCalendarUnit.DayCalendarUnit  | NSCalendarUnit.MonthCalendarUnit  | NSCalendarUnit.YearCalendarUnit, fromDate:NSDate())

println ("Week: = \(dateComponent.weekOfYear)")
```

Hence response should be like below:

```
Week: = 4
```

Comment: Yeah just trying to confirm if there is any error in myDate :)

Comment: I am sorry, guys! I messed up the input date somehow :(

Your solution works fine, bllakjakk. Hence it is the same as my one-liner in my question ;)

Thanks for your effort, Martin R

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger curr_month = [components month];
NSInteger curr_year = [components year];
NSInteger curr_date = [components day];
NSLog(@"%d %d %d, \n Week no: %ld",curr_date, curr_month,curr_year, (long)[components weekOfMonth]);
```

Output is : 2015-01-22 18:19:40.209 Sample[38734:3031191] 22 1 2015,

Week no: 4

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSInteger month = [components month];
    NSInteger year = [components year];
    NSInteger day = [components day];
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[components weekOfMonth]);
```